# How to serve two AngularJS apps with one Express server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, subdomain

I've searched all around and i've found a few ways of how to do this, but none seem to specifically fit my needs and i can't get them to work. My latest attempt is below, using `express-subdomain` with `express` and trying to server two separate AngularJS apps based on the incoming sub domain. This code currently seems to serve the correct app, but none of the Angular modules are included from what i can see. The browser console has many many errors of 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'.  Which from previous experience i believe means AngularJS was not loaded correctly. Keep in mind, i have no issue running only one AngularJS app, it is only when i try to bring in `sub-domain` and serve that second static app.

I've already tried `vhost` with similar failed results.

server.js

```
app.use(subdomain('app1',express.static(__dirname + '/public/app1')));
app.use(subdomain('app2',express.static(__dirname + '/public/app2')));

require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes

app.listen(port);
```

routes.js

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    var firstIndex = req.get('host').indexOf('.');
    var subdomain = req.get('host').substr(0,firstIndex).toLowerCase();
    if (subdomain === 'app1'){
      res.sendFile(root + '/public/app1/views/index.html');
    }else if (subdomain === 'app2'){
      res.sendFile(root + '/public/app2/views/index.html');
    }else{
      res.sendFile(root + '/public/app1/views/notfound.html');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (subdomain === 'app1'){
      res.sendFile(root + '/public/app1/views/index.html');
```

This seems wrong.
This will send index.html to any request, i.e. request for js file.
Should be i.e.:

```
if (subdomain === 'app1' && req.url.indexOf('.') === -1){ 
} else if (subdomain === 'app2' && req.url.indexOf('.') === -1){
} else { /* return static asset */ }  
   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you create a general json whit diferent instance whit the diferents aplicacitions and create all the call, you can emulate this. This is the example:

```
const routes = {
    routeApp1: {
        appTest1:{
            url: '/appTest1/appTest1',
            file: './mock/appTest1.json',
        },
        appTest2:{
            url: '/appTest1/appTest2',
            file: './mock/appTest2.json',
        },
    }

    routeApp2: {
        appTest1:{
            url: '/appTest2/appTest1',
            file: './mock/appTest1.json',
        },
        appTest2:{
            url: '/appTest2/appTest2',
            file: './mock/appTest2.json',
        },
    }
};

app.get(routes.routeApp1.appTest1.url, (req, res) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(require(routes.routeApp1.appTest1.file)));
});

app.get(routes.routeApp2.appTest2.url, (req, res) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(require(routes.routeApp2.appTest2.file)));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Mocks app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Comment: This makes no sense.